# how to implement animation on Button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

Am working on android application and i want to animation on my project. i have some button and image view now i want to add  animation on these button how can i implement these please assist me

```
enter code here
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Btn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        }
    });
```

Comment: i think there is no need to use to set onclicklistener

Comment: then what i use please help me

Comment: @Harry Refer here:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-animation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is code

```
enter code here
final Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.anticlock);
 btn.startAnimation(an);
 an.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv.startAnimation(an);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

In your anim folder paste it as a xml

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1500"
android:fromDegrees="360"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:toDegrees="0" />
```

Comment: what is this (R.anim.anticlock)

Comment: Make a folder anim in your resourece fine